# Ошибка в с++ программа

Tags: c++

Найти сумму под и над главной диагональю 
ПРИМЕР
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9 
над ней будет 2+3+6=11 - правильно, а под 4+7+8=19 , а выдает 15 (7+8) Вот код:`

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int S1, S2, i, j, N, a[10][10];
cout<<"N="; 
cin>>N;
cout<<"Введите элементы матрицы А \n";
for (i=0; i<N; i++)
for (j=0; j<N; j++)
cin>>a[i][j];
for (S1=i=0; i<N; i++)
for (S2=j=0; j<N; j++)
for (j=0; j<N; j++)
//если элемент лежит выше главной диагонали, то наращиваем сумму
{
            if (j>i) 
        {
                S1+=a[i][j];
        }
        else
        {
            if (i>j) 
        {
                S2+=a[i][j]; 
        }
    }
}
cout<<"S1="<<S1<<endl;
cout<<"S2="<<S2<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вот зачем вам `S1=` в `for (S1=i=0; i<N; i++)` (и аналогично в следующем цикле)? Вы понимаете, что в `S1` помещается ноль после в начале каждой новой строчки?

Comment: Как исправить??

Comment: Присваивать нули `S1` и `S2` не там, а перед циклами.

Comment: После ввода перед фор?

Comment: Вы может попробуете, перед тем, как спрашивать?

Answer (score 3):

Проблемный участок был

> `for (S1=i=0; i<N; i++)`
>
> `for (S2=j=0; j<N; j++)`
>
> `for (j=0; j<N; j++)`

**S2 = j = 0**

На каждой итерации цикла `for (S1=i=0; i<N; i++)`
S2 устанавливалось значение 0, т.е. сумма сбрасывалась

цикл `for (j=0; j<N; j++)`

Оказался лишним

---

Надеюсь непротив того что немного привёл к приличному виду код :)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{   
    int sum1 = 0;
    int sum2 = 0;
    
    cout << "N = ";
    int N;
    cin >> N;
    
    cout << "Введите элементы матрицы А: \n";
    // Выделение динамической памяти для массива
    int** arr = new int* [N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        arr[i] = new int [N];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j)
            cin >> arr[i][j];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j)
            if (j > i)
                sum1 += arr[i][j]; // если элемент лежит выше главной диагонали, то наращиваем сумму
            else if (i > j)
                sum2 += arr[i][j];

    cout << "S1=" << sum1 << endl;
    cout << "S2=" << sum2 << endl;

    // Освобождение выделеной памяти для массива
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        delete[] arr[i];
    delete[] arr;

    return 0;
}
```